# How to automatically reload style variant .json?

Tags: block-editor, theme.json

New block editor themes like twentytwentythree allow style variations. You can change colors and fonts from the site editor. A style variation is just a `.json` file that gets merged with `theme.json`.

My problem with developing a style variation is that changes to my `.json` file are not applied automatically. I have to reload the site editor, select another variation, select my variation, and apply. Is there a way to auto apply my variation? Or how do people design themes based on block themes nowadays? I think alternatively I could edit `theme.json` directly, or use a plugin that allows me to customize it - or give up and develop a classic theme.

Here is an [issue where the problem is discussed](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/43395). Note the problem I have is *not* that the theme is cached, that is a separate issue. The problem is that there is a lot of friction when I want to see my changes in Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your frustration. In short, I don't think it's possible to I've been dabbling with FSE themes on and off (I adopted one for a site just a couple weeks ago)
I came to the conclusions/principles that seem to be unspoken or assumed (maybe they're written elsewhere) about the full site editor:

- Modifications to your theme are meant to be done in the GUI not in the theme's files (e.g. theme.json, html files). [There are some settings that can only be done in theme.json](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/44340) but it seems to me that more and more are to be done in the GUI site editor.

(As you're probably aware, for users who are comfortable with editing text files ; modify some theme settings is may take longer in the GUI than it would to edit a text file. This also makes version control more burdensome.

As a result, when I made changes to my block-based theme in my local wordpress installation and wanted to apply them on a remote server, I had to export the entire database locally; upload the .sql to my remote server and import the local database dump (granted this can be expedited through plugins or wp-cli).

This was the only way that I found where changes to theme.json and template files would be consistently applied.

In the past with classic themes, I'd just FTP or rsync the theme directory to the remote server.

I had this same question - [how to sync changes made to theme files with the block editor](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/22469) , a couple years ago, and it's still largely unaddressed.